# Do we ***really*** need "What Easter Eggs have you placed in code?" back in the wild again?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, undeleted-questions

I'm having a real hard time figuring out why ten people felt it was necessary to undelete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140376/what-easter-eggs-have-you-placed-in-code.

Yes, it's a community wiki question, but does it add *anything* at all to Stack Overflow?  Honestly, why undelete a community-wiki poll question that's been dead and gone for over three years?

I know some people have pointed out that I've been a bit zealous in the past at deleting questions, but this is like the opposite end of the pendulum here.

I half-expect the re-open votes to start pouring in shortly.

Comment: I like to have some fun once in a while :-) I'd like it to stay, but that's only my opinion. A Historical Lock on it would be good though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question [does not meet the views criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) to be retained as a `Historical Significance` locked question.

It's [also been brought up on Meta to be undeleted before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123462/may-we-please-have-the-so-easter-egg-question-back).

It also does not meet the criteria for "where we hate fun":

> 

1. Does this question match the criteria provided in the Stack Overflow FAQ?
2. Is this question accepted by the community, as reflected in upvotes, favorites, views, and answers?
3. Does this question teach me anything that could make me better at my job? Can I learn something from it?

No, Maybe (if we're stretching it), and No.

Therefore, [it should be deleted](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), or *at best*, locked for all eternity.

Comment: It's important to note that I prefer to keep good content around. I use the above criteria in determining 'good'. This doesn't mean I believe all off-topic questions should be deleted, only that this one doesn't meet the criteria for us to save it.

Comment: I would answer yes to #3 to a question about software Easter eggs - provided they were reasonably-scoped, actual implementation questions. This particular question, while well-known in its time, had woefully little more educational value to offer than what sorts of *ideas* people had for eggs in their own projects. That's not to say that inspiration is bad or worthless, but all you have are anecdotes of end results, and not much (if any at all) of the process.